# How i can pass existing data from my store to formik?

Tags: reactjs, formik

I have a hook component that uses `useFormik()` and this is my initial values:

```
const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {login: '', password: '', inactive: false},
    validationSchema: schema, 
    onSubmit: async (values, { resetForm }) => {
        await dispatch(UserActions.createUser(values, resetForm))
    },
})
```

Sometimes this component already have data, so i try to check this in useEffect and set the initialState by then:

```
const userEditing = useSelector(store => store.userStates.userEditing)
const [initialValues, setInitialValues] = useState('')

useEffect(() => {
    if (userEditing) {
        setInitialValues(userEditing)
    } else {
        setInitialValues({login: '', password: '', inactive: false})
    }
}, []); // eslint-disable-line
```

and then i try to put this variable in `initialValues`:

```
const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: initialValues,
    validationSchema: schema, 
    onSubmit: async (values, { resetForm }) => {
        await dispatch(UserActions.createUser(values, resetForm))
    },
})
```

Is entering in the `if()` condition but my inputs is not being filled with this values.

How i can pass existing data from my store to formik?

This is my template:

```
<Grid item xs={5}>
    <TextField
        value={formik.values.login}
        onChange={formik.handleChange}
        onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
        helperText={formik.touched.login ? formik.errors.login : ""}
        error={formik.touched.login && Boolean(formik.errors.login)}
        variant="outlined"
        margin="normal"
        required
        fullWidth
        id="email"
        label="E-mail"
        name="login"
        autoComplete="email"
    />
</Grid>

<Grid item xs={5}>
    <TextField
        value={formik.values.password}
        onChange={formik.handleChange}
        onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
        helperText={formik.touched.password ? formik.errors.password : ""}
        error={formik.touched.password && Boolean(formik.errors.password)}
        variant="outlined"
        margin="normal"
        required
        fullWidth
        type="password"
        id="password"
        label="Senha"
        name="password"
    />
</Grid>

<Grid item xs={2}>
    <FormControlLabel
        onChange={formik.handleChange}
        onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
        value={formik.values.inactive}
        control={<Switch color="primary" />}
        label="Inativo"
        labelPlacement="top"
    />
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 2):

Pass `enableReinitialize={true}` to Formik wrapper.